# @aws-amplify version of aws-amplify-react Connect

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

What is the @aws-amplify version of aws-amplify-react ***Connect*** component.

aws-amplify-react has [Connect component.](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui-legacy/api/connect/q/framework/react)
I need to migrate to latest [@aws-amplify](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/q/framework/react).

Comment: Connect allows to interact with your GraphQL API. Amplify can be used with various frameworks, such as React, Vue, Angular, Flutter... Does that answer? 
If not, could you put more context in your question? (i.e do you intend to use Connect in a Vue project for instance?)

Comment: I’ve developed a react app with aws amplify. The app uses AWS-amplify-react package. The new version of aws-amplify-react is @ aws-amplify. Legacy package had Connect hoc react component. I’m unable to find the counterpart component for it in @aws-amplify.

Comment: So I think you need to use the API directly (connect does not exist anymore in the new library). I use to use API.graphqlgraphqlOperation(...) (or the rest one). They made things even more straightforward. Let me know if this answers.

Comment: @DavidThery any idea on AmplifyS3ImagePicker is used?